# How to get rid of or hide `NFC detection notification` and `complete action using pop up`?

Tags: android, android-notifications, nfc, android-popupwindow

I made an app that uses NFC read.

I use `singleTask` for avoiding duplicate screen pop ups.

```
<activity
    android:name=".view.main.MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data
            android:host="example.com"
            android:scheme="http">
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And I use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`

```
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) // or?? and??
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0)
```

I use `Hauwei Mate 20 Pro`. And it keeps getting `NFC detection Notificaiton` and sometimes get `complete action using pop up`.
How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you use `enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, writeTagFilters, null);` 
in `onResume()`, and`nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);`
ìn `onPause()`?